# CREATE VIEW if 'a' not null and 'b' not null then return 'a' and 'b' else null

Tags: postgresql, view, syntax

I am creating a view in postgres using the pgAdmin SQL window and having real trouble with the syntax for a particular part of the query.

I'd like to be able to state: where both a and b are not null then return the values for a and b, else return null.

I've started off looking at the CASE THEN ELSE statement but really can't figure this out. Any help greatly appreciated.

- SELECT a, b,
- CASE
- WHEN a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL
- THEN a = a AND b = b
- ELSE false
- END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a,b,
case when a is not null and b is not null then a else null end,
case when a is not null and b is not null then b else null end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow. It's always better to explain what the code does and how it addresses the question. This helps future users.